Grant permission for a user to create objects in a PostgreSQL schema is not working
I have recently upgraded to PostgreSQL 15 and observed that a db user say X (not a owner of schema) is no longer able to create a table in public schema. From the below release notes looks like it is now restricted on who can create objects.
PostgreSQL 15 revokes the CREATE permission from all users except a database owner from the public (or default) schema 

In order to resolve this I am trying to grant create permission to user X on public schema but it is not working. Below are the commands which I tried. I am a developer with not much DB background, so not sure what I am missing here. Could you please help.
I have another user, say Y, which I have used to grant the "create" permission.
postgres=> \du+
                                            List of roles
 Role name   |     Attributes          |      Member of      
-------------+------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 X           | Create DB               |   {}
 Y           | Create role, Create DB  | {rds_superuser}
rds_superuser| Cannot login            | {pg_read_all_data,pg_write_all_data,pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend,pg_checkpoint,rds_replication,rds_password}
..

Grant "CREATE" permission to user 'X' on public schema by super user 'Y'.
postgres=> GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO X;
GRANT

The output of the command is GRANT. So I am assuming that it is executed successfully.
However when I run the below command as user X, it shows that "CREATE" permission is not assigned on the public schema.
WITH "names"("name") AS (  SELECT n.nspname AS "name"
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
      WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
        AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
) SELECT "name",
  pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(current_user, "name", 'CREATE') AS "create",
  pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(current_user, "name", 'USAGE') AS "usage"
    FROM "names";

--------+--------+-------
  name  | create | usage
--------+--------+-------
 public | f      | t
(1 row)


What do you get if you run \dn+ public using psql? If that looks the same, then the only explanation is that you ran the GRANT in the wrong database.
